# How to catch DataCloneError in Worker?

Tags: html, web-worker

I have a HTML5 worker which sends values with `postMessage`. Sometimes (for example if the result is a function) the code throws an exception:

> DataCloneError: The object could not be cloned.

So I tried to catch the exception:

```
try {
  self.postMessage (result);
}
catch (ex) {
  if (ex instanceof DataCloneError)
    self.postMessage (result.toString());
  else
    throw ex;
}
```

But this throws the following exception:

> ReferenceError: DataCloneError is not defined

I am confused. How to catch the `DataCloneError`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you receive is an instance of the [DOMException](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMException) interface.

To know which DOMException it is, you can check its `name` property.
The one of DATA_CLONE_ERROR, is `"DataCloneError"`.

```js
try {
  postMessage( () => {} , '*' );
}
catch( err ) {
  console.log( err.name === "DataCloneError" );
}
```